how to send data with com port?
namespace WindowsApplication14
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort _serialPort;

        // delegate is used to write to a UI control from a non-UI thread
        private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Makes sure serial port is open before trying to write
            try
            {
                if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
                    _serialPort.Open();

                _serialPort.Write("%DS0010110011130000000bilgi+islem+test0100380112530100380152492552552480000560010000**CR");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error opening/writing to serial port :: " + ex.Message, "Error!");
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // all of the options for a serial device
            // can be sent through the constructor of the SerialPort class
            // PortName = "COM1", Baud Rate = 19200, Parity = None, 
            // Data Bits = 8, Stop Bits = One, Handshake = None
            _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 38400, Parity.Odd, 8, StopBits.One);
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.Open();
        }

        void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            string data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new object[] { data });
        }

        private void si_DataReceived(string data)
        {
            textBox1.Text = data.Trim();
        }
    }
}

I am trying to send configuration to the device via com port connection, but it gives the following error. Where am i making a mistake?

I am trying to send configuration to the device via com port connection, but it gives the following error. where am i making a mistake?

Maybe the question title doesn't match the situation? If you want to send, it's best not to receive. Isn't the problem that the ReadLine() is timeout, not the Write()? According to these SerialPort.ReadLine Method, SerialPort.NewLine Property, the default NewLine code is LineFeed, so why not change it to CarriageReturn?

The comments in code say that the COM port should be configure as 8, N, 1, but you're setting the Parity to Odd instead of None -- Not related: you don't need an explicit delegate, you can write just BeginInvoke(() => si_DataReceived(data));

Don't set the Timeout properties until you've debugged your code, you could surround those property setters with #if Debug.  Handshake.None is unlikely to be correct, if you do that then you have to set the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to true yourself.  But high odds it should be Handshake.RequestToSend

Are you sure device is meant to return something? If not, then remove the sp_DataReceived function or don't use it. ReadLine expects something to be in the input buffer, but after timeout, if nothing is received, it will throw the exception.

Try this code:
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string data = sp.ReadExisting();
        this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new object[] { data });
    }

